# Etsy - get sales amount

Tags: api, web-scraping, e-commerce, etsy

I'm trying to get the sales amount info of a specific product on Etsy, but I can't find the API request on the official Etsy or even a third-party API.
I know the following services are getting this data but I know how:

- Alura
- EtsyHunt
- Insightfactory

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: I can see the etst API V3  documentation 
https://developers.etsy.com/documentation/reference

Comment: I know there is an officail api for Etsy. That's not my question.

Comment: You dont get via API. They add the total sales number with the price. They also factor in the historical prices too/

Comment: So only the total number is available?

Answer (score 3):

the reality about those services is that they most of the time don't know the sales of the products they analyse. Everbee, etsyHunt or Erank all those services use their own algorithm to give an average sales number for the listings.

Mixing the data available using the Etsy API, favorites, total sales and visits.

Another way to get more data is to link your own shop on their websites so they can scrape your data and probably use it to improve their services. But in the same time, they are probably near the reality for the big players on Etsy, because those shops probably use those services...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).